# Module error when running JavaFx media application

Tags: java, javafx, module

When I run my `JavaFX` 11 application with the following command:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java 
-p ~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-swing/11/javafx-swing-11.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-swing/11/javafx-swing-11-linux.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/11/javafx-graphics-11.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/11/javafx-graphics-11-linux.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/11/javafx-base-11.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/11/javafx-base-11-linux.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/11/javafx-controls-11.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/11/javafx-controls-11-linux.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-media/11/javafx-media-11.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-media/11/javafx-media-11-linux.jar 
--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics
-classpath ~/development/intellij/OpenPatrician/OpenPatricianStandalone/target/classes:
~/.OpenPatrician/plugins/maps/MinimalMap-Plugin.jar:
~/development/intellij/OpenPatrician/OpenPatricianDisplay/target/classes:
~/.m2/repository/ch/sahits/sahitsUtil/1.2.4/sahitsUtil-1.2.4.jar:
~/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2/2.1.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-log4j2-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.11.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.1.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.11.1/log4j-api-2.11.1.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.11.1/log4j-core-2.11.1.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-jul/2.11.1/log4j-jul-2.11.1.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.25/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:
~/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.4/commons-cli-1.4.jar:
~/development/intellij/OpenPatrician/OpenPatricianImage/target/classes:
~/development/intellij/OpenPatrician/OpenPatricianModel/target/classes:
~/development/intellij/OpenPatrician/GameEvent/target/classes:
~/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/2.3.1/txw2-2.3.1.jar:
~/.m2/repository/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.7/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/staxex/stax-ex/1.8/stax-ex-1.8.jar:
~/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/fastinfoset/FastInfoset/1.2.15/FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar:
~/.m2/repository/javax/activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-swing/11/javafx-swing-11.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-swing/11/javafx-swing-11-linux.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/11/javafx-graphics-11.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/11/javafx-graphics-11-linux.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/11/javafx-base-11.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/11/javafx-base-11-linux.jar:
~/development/intellij/OpenPatrician/OpenPatricianSound/target/classes:
~/development/intellij/OpenPatrician/OpenPatricianUtilities/target/classes:
~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.1.2.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/11/javafx-controls-11.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/11/javafx-controls-11-linux.jar:
~/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar:
~/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.10/xstream-1.4.10.jar:
~/.m2/repository/xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar:
~/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar:
~/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:
~/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-media/11/javafx-media-11.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-media/11/javafx-media-11-linux.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.1.2.RELEASE/spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.1.2.RELEASE/spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.1.2.RELEASE/spring-expression-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-oxm/5.1.2.RELEASE/spring-oxm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:
~/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/24.1-jre/guava-24.1-jre.jar:
~/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-compat-qual/2.0.0/checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar:
~/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.1.3/error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar:
~/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.1/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/animal-sniffer-annotations/1.14/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar:
~/development/intellij/OpenPatrician/OpenPatricianJavaFX/target/classes:
~/development/intellij/OpenPatrician/OpenPatricianGameEvent/target/classes:
~/development/intellij/OpenPatrician/OpenPatricianClientServerInterface/target/classes:
~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.1.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.1.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.23/snakeyaml-1.23.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.2/aspectjweaver-1.9.2.jar:
~/development/intellij/OpenPatrician/OpenPatricianServer/target/classes:
~/development/intellij/OpenPatrician/OpenPatricianEngine/target/classes:
~/.m2/repository/com/carrotsearch/hppc/0.7.2/hppc-0.7.2.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.2.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.1.2.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/reflections/reflections/0.9.11/reflections-0.9.11.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.21.0-GA/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:
~/development/intellij/OpenPatrician/OpenPatricianData/target/classes:
~/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.2/lombok-1.18.2.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-devtools/2.1.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-devtools-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.1.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:
~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.1.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar 
ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.standalone.OpenPatricianApplication
```

I run into this error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager (in unnamed module @0x4d7be377) cannot access class com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.glass.utils to unnamed module @0x4d7be377
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.lambda$new$0(NativeMediaManager.java:136)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.<init>(NativeMediaManager.java:107)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager$NativeMediaManagerInitializer.<clinit>(NativeMediaManager.java:78)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getDefaultInstance(NativeMediaManager.java:90)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.canPlayProtocol(MediaManager.java:78)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:239)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaAudioClip.<init>(NativeMediaAudioClip.java:53)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaAudioClip.load(NativeMediaAudioClip.java:63)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.AudioClipProvider.load(AudioClipProvider.java:66)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.AudioClip.load(AudioClip.java:135)
    at javafx.scene.media.AudioClip.<init>(AudioClip.java:83)
    at ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.sound.impl.LoopTrack.lambda$new$0(LoopTrack.java:26)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

As I understand this exception there is something wrong with my module setup, but I am not clear what I need to change:

- Add additional modules to `--add-modules` and which?
- Add `--add-opens` to the command with which modules
- Something completely different?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You need to make sure `javafx.media` is resolved as a module from the module-path. You can do this by:

1. Including it in the VM arguments: `--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.media`
2. Or making your own code modular, adding an appropriate `requires javafx.media;` directive to your module descriptor, and using `--module` to launch your application.
3. Or using a JDK that includes JavaFX.

If you're not sure how or where to set the VM arguments in your IDE and/or build tool, check out [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

---

## The Problem

The error is related to the *Java Platform Module System*, added in Java 9. If you're not aware of what modules are and how they work, check out this blog: [Understanding Java 9 Modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html). Here's a small excerpt:

> Modularity adds a higher level of aggregation above packages. The key new language element is the module—a uniquely named, reusable group of related packages, as well as resources (such as images and XML files) and a module descriptor specifying
>
> - the module’s name
> - the module’s dependencies (that is, other modules this module depends on)
> - the packages it explicitly makes available to other modules (all other packages in the module are implicitly unavailable to other modules)
> - the services it offers
> - the services it consumes
> - to what other modules it allows reflection

With the introduction of modules, JavaFX was also modularized. It is now made up of seven modules, as can be seen by [its Javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/). These modules share some of their internals between themselves, but not with application developers. This is accomplished through *qualified* exports/opens directives.

### Your Error

This is your error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager (in unnamed module @0x4d7be377) cannot access class com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.glass.utils to unnamed module @0x4d7be377
```

It's telling you a class in the *unnamed module* is attempting to access a class in a different, named module: `javafx.graphics`. However, the latter module does not export the needed package to at least the unnamed module. Looking at the error message and the given class names, we can deduce that the class in the unnamed module is part of JavaFX's media implementation. This suggests the class *should* be in the `javafx.media` module. Then why does the error mention the unnamed module?

The unnamed module is the module all classes on the class-path belong to. What this means is that the `javafx.media` module was put on the class-path and lost its identity. A consequence of this is that all the qualified exports/opens directives declared by the `javafx.graphics` module which grant the `javafx.media` module the necessary access no longer apply—hence the `IllegalAccessError`.

### But... You Used the Module-Path

From the command line you provided in your question we can see the `javafx-media-11.jar` file was placed on the module-path (`-p`). So what is the problem? The problem is caused by placing the media JAR file on *both* the module-path *and* the class-path, while simultaneously failing to ensure the `javafx.media` module is resolved as a module.

The algorithm for module resolution is described by the [`java.lang.module`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/package-summary.html) package documentation. Basically, it starts with a set of root modules and then recursively enumerates the requires directives. The root modules are determined by the `--add-modules` and `--module` arguments. Your code isn't modular, meaning you don't use `--module`, and you have:

```
--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics
```

In other words, none of the root modules directly or indirectly require the `javafx.media` module, thus it is never resolved. Since the classes are also on the class-path they're still found, but now in the unnamed module. If you had not placed the JavaFX dependencies on the class-path as well then you'd be getting a `ClassNotFoundException`.

---

## The Solution

The solution is simple: Make sure the `javafx.media` module is resolved. There are at least three ways to accomplish this:

### (1) Include the Module in the `--add-modules` Argument

```
--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.media
```

Note you don't need to specify the `javafx.graphics` module as it'll be pulled in implicitly by the other modules; both `javafx.controls` and `javafx.media` require `javafx.graphics`. The same general reasoning also applies to the `javafx.base` module in this case.

The [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) guides show how to configure the VM options for JavaFX in each of the major IDEs (i.e. IntelliJ, Eclipse, and NetBeans) and build tools (i.e. Maven and Gradle).

### (2) Make Your Own Code Modular

```java
module app {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.media;

    // replace with your Application class' package
    exports com.example.app to javafx.graphics;
}
```

Then make sure to launch your application with `--module` (I expect modern versions of IDEs and build tools will do this for you if your code has a `module-info` descriptor).

Notice the qualified exports to `javafx.graphics`. [This is required](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) in order for JavaFX to reflectively instantiate your application class. There are similar requirements (qualified `opens`) [for FXML controllers](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXML.html) and other APIs which require private reflective access.

### (3) Use a JDK that Includes JavaFX

With JavaFX part of the run-time image, it will always be resolved as named modules. There are two distributions of OpenJDK that include OpenJFX that I know of:

1. [BellSoft Liberica](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/) (make sure to download "Full JDK")
2. [Azul Zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk-fx#zulu) (make sure to download "JDK FX")

Note it's also possible to [create your own JDK via `jlink`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76155054/6395627).

### Bouns "Solution"

***Warning:** This approach is [not supported](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8256362)*.

There is another option: Place everything on the class-path, including the JavaFX modules, and ignore JPMS modules completely. If you do this your main-class **must not** be a subclass of `Application`. You'd have to create a separate launcher class that simply launches JavaFX.

---

If you use Maven, you can see how to rely on the JavaFX media module here as a dependency here:

- [JavaFX media player import (Maven)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69978264/1155209)

Comment: This simple line ended my Misery, I am working on Windows 10 JavaFx 11
**--module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.media**

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `VSCode`, here's a simple solution to your problem:

In the java proyect exist a folder called `.vscode`, inside this exist a .json file called `launch.json`.

*directory:* [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfZ2g.png)

*launch.json:*

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch Main",
            "request": "launch",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path /Users/ASUS/javafx-sdk-16/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
            "mainClass": "main.java.Main",
            "projectName": "MorseJavaFx_41229da3"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, in the line "`vmArgs`", you must add `javafx.media` to the final and inside the quotes, like this:

```
"vmArgs": "--module-path /Users/ASUS/javafx-sdk-16/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml, javafx.media"
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using NetBeans right click on your proyect, go to properties -> run, and in "VM Option" put the line to add modules --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.media".

In my case I also had the "javafx.fxml" so I had to keep it in the VM options:
--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.media