# Why Parent root =FXMLLoader is not working properly?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to build an app in JavaFX but i am facing the issue.
Below code generating error.I error are showing since i created the project.
I downloaded the JavaFX 14 from "https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/" and include all jar files present in lib directory.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

But This code works fine

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        //Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        StackPane root=new StackPane();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Getting this error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\java.exe" --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=60984:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath E:\Shapes\out\production\Shapes;E:\Software\javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1\lib\javafx-swt.jar;E:\Software\javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1\lib\javafx.base.jar;E:\Software\javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1\lib\javafx.controls.jar;E:\Software\javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;E:\Software\javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1\lib\javafx.graphics.jar;E:\Software\javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1\lib\javafx.media.jar;E:\Software\javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1\lib\javafx.swing.jar;E:\Software\javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1\lib\javafx.web.jar -p E:\Software\javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1\lib\javafx.base.jar;E:\Software\javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1\lib\javafx.graphics.jar sample.Main
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x66dac2b5) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x66dac2b5
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2056)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is this a modular or non-modular project? You need to open your package to the `javafx.fxml` module, but how you do that depends on whether your project is modular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental error is (formatted for readability):

```java
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: 
    class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x66dac2b5) 
    cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) 
    because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x66dac2b5
```

That error is telling you that the `javafx.fxml` module has ended up on the class-path while the `javafx.graphics` module is on the module-path. This scenario prevents the special access to internal code the `javafx.graphics` module grants to the `javafx.fxml` module.

The solution to this is to do one of the following:

1. Include `javafx.fxml` in your `--add-modules` VM argument.
2. Make your own code modular, add the necessary *requires*, *exports*, and *opens* directives, and launch your application with `--module`.

If you're curious about how the above error comes about then [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53237667/6395627) goes into more detail. Note it focuses on the `javafx.media` module but the concept is the same.

Comment: I Just go to "https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/" and copy the Add VM Option "--module-path /path/to/javafx-sdk-14/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml" for Linux and Mac and "--module-path "\path\to\javafx-sdk-14\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml" for Windows and open Run>>Edit Configuration>>VM Option and Paste it there and Boom its Working.