# Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException and more JavaFx Errors

Tags: java, javafx

I can`t find my mistake. I want to play a short Video before starting my game. I was trying to do that with JavaFX. And my code should be right, but i am not sure about those errors. My runpath ; --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-15\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
I am thankful for every answer

The testcode of the class i want to run:

```
public class Intro extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("Enter The Dungeon");
        Group root = new Group();

        Media media = new Media("Video/test.avi");
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        MediaView view = new MediaView(player);
        root.getChildren().add(view);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400, Color.BLACK);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        player.play();
    }
}













Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri.getScheme() == null! uri == 'Video/test.avi'
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:218)
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:393)
    at etd.dungeon.resource.Intro.start(Intro.java:23)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application etd.dungeon.resource.Intro
```

Comment: you have to add the media module

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237287/module-error-when-running-javafx-media-application

Comment: Did not help unfortunatly

Comment: You should add the stack trace to your question