# Playing Media/AudioClip in JavaFX with Java14

Tags: java, javafx, java-14

I am trying to play a sound in a JavaFX application but am failing to do so because of this error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager (in unnamed module @0xea8bc0f) cannot access class com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.glass.utils to unnamed module @0xea8bc0f
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.lambda$new$0(NativeMediaManager.java:110)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.<init>(NativeMediaManager.java:107)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager$NativeMediaManagerInitializer.<clinit>(NativeMediaManager.java:78)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getDefaultInstance(NativeMediaManager.java:90)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.canPlayProtocol(MediaManager.java:78)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:239)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaAudioClip.<init>(NativeMediaAudioClip.java:53)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaAudioClip.load(NativeMediaAudioClip.java:63)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.AudioClipProvider.load(AudioClipProvider.java:66)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.AudioClip.load(AudioClip.java:135)
    at javafx.scene.media.AudioClip.<init>(AudioClip.java:83)
    at sample.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:46)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
```

I am using Java 14 and JavaFX 14. I tried to use a local file or passing an URI to the Media/AudioClip but I always end up with this error.

Some Code snippets, I tried: (all of them lead to the same result)

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tetris");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
        AudioClip media = new AudioClip("https://ia800504.us.archive.org/33/items/TetrisThemeMusic/Tetris.mp3");
        media.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with MediaPlayer and local file:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tetris");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
        Media media = new Media(new File("Tetris.mp3").toURI().toString());
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I always get the same error, I tried adding `--add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass=ALL-UNNAMED` to the VM arguments but it didn't change anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237287/module-error-when-running-javafx-media-application check this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jabir's comment I read in the other stackoverflow question that all I was missing was the addition of `javafx.media` to my declared `--add-modules` in the VM arguments