# JavaFX 11 WebView LoadException

Tags: javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I have been endeavouring to implement a JavaFX application using FXML which includes a WebView.

However, when run this results in a ClassNotFoundException:javafx.scene.web.WebView leading to a javafx.fxml.LoadException, but I am perplexed by this.

Consequently, I have created a simplified application as follows. The Controller is empty in this example. If anybody can inform me how to successfully implement a WebView it will be much appreciated.

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("wv.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("WebView Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

wv.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>

<FlowPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
      <WebView fx:id="WV" prefWidth="200" prefHeight="200"></WebView>

</FlowPane>
```

module-info.java

```
module WebViewTest {

    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;

    opens sample;
}
```

Comment: please edit and add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module error when running JavaFx media application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237287/module-error-when-running-javafx-media-application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at your module-info and wonder why you don't have javafx.web in there.

Comment: Thank you, inserting javafx.web to module-info resolved the issue. Much appreciated.