# JavaFX - module javafx.base does not export com.sun.javafx to unnamed module

Tags: java, maven, javafx, module

JavaFX - Adding an AudioClip results in: "module javafx.base does not export com.sun.javafx to unnamed module" [Maven]

JavaFX worked nice until i tried to add an AudioClip:
I tried everything i found online, nothing changed tou :(

Im out of ideas.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.PlatformManager (in unnamed module @0x3f3afe78) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.PlatformUtil (in module javafx.base) because module javafx.base does not export com.sun.javafx to unnamed module @0x3f3afe78
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.PlatformManager.getSupportedProtocols(PlatformManager.java:203)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.loadProtocols(NativeMediaManager.java:197)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.canPlayProtocol(NativeMediaManager.java:267)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.canPlayProtocol(MediaManager.java:78)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:239)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaAudioClip.<init>(NativeMediaAudioClip.java:53)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaAudioClip.load(NativeMediaAudioClip.java:63)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.AudioClipProvider.load(AudioClipProvider.java:66)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.AudioClip.load(AudioClip.java:135)
    at javafx.scene.media.AudioClip.<init>(AudioClip.java:83)
```

Comment: Please post text an no pictures...

Comment: sry, better now?

Comment: Your error looks like a variation of the one covered in this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237287/module-error-when-running-javafx-media-application