# I have a problem with an error about JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have installed everything for JavaFX but there is a problem I can't fix. Can someone help me?

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.fxml not found

I installed everything for a JavaFX project. I added the library and did the VM arguments, yet I can't fix the boot layer.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237287/module-error-when-running-javafx-media-application

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/