# How to play a sound onMousePressed with JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, audio

I am trying to play a 1 second clip when a user presses anywhere on the Scene. I've created an EventHandler to process the click, and it works for everything other than playing a sound. I get this error when I run the program:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator (in unnamed module @0x1ac0e4eb) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.PlatformUtil (in module javafx.base) because module javafx.base does not export com.sun.javafx to unnamed module @0x1ac0e4eb
```

Here is my code:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
...
scene.setOnMousePressed(this::processMousePress);
...
}
```

and the event handler:

```
public void processMousePress(MouseEvent event)
    {
        
        Media sound = new Media(getClass().getResource("wrong-answer.mp3").toExternalForm());
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }
```

Any idea why this is happening? When I use Sysout to make sure the MousePressed event is working, everything works fine. However, once I add the sound, I get the above error.

Comment: Regarding the `IllegalAccessError`, the message is slightly different, but the underlying problem and general solution is likely the same as discussed in the [Module error when running JavaFx media application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53237287/6395627) Q&A. In short, you appear to have some JavaFX modules loaded from the module-path, but other JavaFX modules are being loaded from the class-path (i.e., unnamed module). Make sure _all_ JavaFX modules are loaded from the module-path or, if you're okay with a technically unsupported configuration, _all_ are loaded from the class-path.

Comment: But see jewelsea's answer below for a better approach (i.e., `AudioClip` instead of `MediaPlayer`). Also, the example in that answer is modular, so Maven (the build tool used for the example) will place all code on the module-path, meaning all JavaFX modules will be resolved as named modules (thus solving your `IllegalAccessError`).

Answer (score 3):

**Suggestions**

1. [`AudioClip`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html) is more appropriate for the kind of thing you are doing  (playing a short, one-second sound) rather than `Media` and `MediaPlayer`.
2. You can cache the `AudioClip` so you only have one instance, instead of creating and loading new media every time you play (which will be less responsive and more resource intensive).
3. Playing a single AudioClip instance multiple times simultaneously is not a problem.
4. You should be loading JavaFX classes from modules, not the unnamed module (classpath).  See [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) on how to use JavaFX modules.

**How to use AudioClip**

From the javadoc:

```
AudioClip plonkSound =
  new AudioClip(
    "http://somehost/path/plonk.aiff"
  );
plonkSound.play();
```

**Example**

This will load a pokemon level up sound off a url location on the web and play it.  The sound is played on the action event of a button, but playing in response to other events like mouse presses is similar.  Hammer the button quickly in rapid succession to level up your pokemon rapidly with gratifying audio feedback.

*src/main/java/module-info.java*

```
module com.example.audioclipplayer {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.media;

    exports com.example.audioclipplayer;
}
```

*src/main/java/com/example/audioclipplayer/AudioClipPlayer.java*

```
package com.example.audioclipplayer;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AudioClipPlayer extends Application {
    private static final String POKEMON_LEVEL_UP_SOUND_URL = 
            "https://www.myinstants.com/media/sounds/12_3.mp3";
    private static final String POKEMON_LEVEL_UP_SOUND_RESOURCE_NAME = 
            "pokemon-level-up.mp3";

    private AudioClip clip;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        clip = new AudioClip(POKEMON_LEVEL_UP_SOUND_URL);
// If loading from a resource rather than a network URL, then use this code:
//        clip = new AudioClip(
//                Objects.requireNonNull(
//                        AudioClipPlayer.class.getResource(
//                                POKEMON_LEVEL_UP_SOUND_RESOURCE_NAME
//                        )
//                ).toExternalForm()
//        );
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button play = new Button("Play");
        play.setOnAction(e -> clip.play());

        StackPane layout = new StackPane(play);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*pom.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>AudioClipPlayer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>AudioClipPlayer</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <javafx.version>21</javafx.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Sounds as resources**

Usually, you will put short AudioClip sounds as resources in your application and [load resources as specified here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other).

To do this for the sample above:

1. Download the mp3 manually from the network location provided in the app.
2. Place it in `src/main/resources/com/example/audioclipplayer/pokemon-level-up.mp3`.
3. Use the resource lookup code in the example to load the sound, rather than the network URL loading code.