# How can I use two sounds at the same time in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I have a song that's always playing. I want to add more sound when hovering over the buttons, the method with sound when hovering works, but there is no sound, only the main song plays. Code examples below.

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {

private static Scene scene;
private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private static Media media;
private String backSongURL = "path mp3";

final int sizeW = 640;
final int sizeH = 480;

@Override
public void start(@SuppressWarnings("exports") Stage stage) throws IOException {

    scene = new Scene(loadFXML("main"), sizeW, sizeH);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    BackMusic();

}

static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
    scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
}

private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
    return fxmlLoader.load();
}

public void BackMusic() { // add music to background

    media = new Media(new File(backSongURL).toURI().toString());
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);

    mediaPlayer.setCycleCount(999999999);
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.2);
    mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
}
```

**MainController(or Menu)**

```
@FXML
public void btnSong() { 

    media = new Media(new File(btnSongURL).toURI().toString());
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);

    mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.9);
    mediaPlayer.stop();

}
```

Method btnSongs if you run debugging and look at it all goes through without problems, but there is no sound on the keys. For modeling of the interface and code binding I used SceneBuilder

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Your fixes worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the button "song" actually a long song or just a short sound?

**Short Audio**

If a short sound, use an [`AudioClip`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html).

- [How to play a sound onMousePressed with JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77449583/how-to-play-a-sound-onmousepressed-with-javafx/)

The above link is for playing a sound when a mouse is pressed. For a button press play the audio in the button action handler rather than the mouse event handler.

**Long Audio**

If a long song, you need to call `mediaPlayer.play()` to start playing media, not `mediaPlayer.stop()` (which is what you call in the code in your question).

As long as you are playing the sound in a different media player and keep references to the media players while the sound is playing, then you can play more than one sound at once without any issue.

You want to cache the media and player in a different variable than your background music, so one or the other doesn't get prematurely garbage collected before your audio completes playing.

You also want to load the media once upfront, rather than every time you play it, so that will be no delay.  For background music, a delay when starting media is probably OK, but for a sound designed to coincide with a button press, a delay is not ideal.

Oracle provides a full [tutorial for using a MediaPlayer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/playercontrol.htm).  The Oracle tutorial is old and for Java 8, but most of the code is fine.  For modern JavaFX versions, you also need to [require the `javafx.media` module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69976938/javafx-mediaplayer-import) to be able to use it.

As noted by the asker in comments:

> Your fixes worked