JavaFX IllegalAccessError when trying to use media player
I am trying to make an mp3 player using javaFX but I keep getting this error whenever I am trying to create a Media object.
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator (in unnamed module @0x4b92dfda) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.PlatformUtil (in module javafx.base) because module javafx.base does not export com.sun.javafx to unnamed module @0x4b92dfda
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:235)
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:392)
    at MusicPlayer.openFile(MusicPlayer.java:105)
    at MusicPlayer.lambda$0(MusicPlayer.java:67)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@22/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@22/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8917)
    at javafx.controls@22/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@22/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:207)
    at javafx.controls@22/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@22/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@22/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@22/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3985)
    at javafx.graphics@22/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1891)
    at javafx.graphics@22/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2709)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:430)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

The method that is giving me this error looks like this and the Media media = new Media(filePath); line is the 105th where the error begins.
    private void openFile() {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Open MP3 File");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("MP3 Files", "*.mp3")
        );
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());
        if (selectedFile != null) {
            try {
                String filePath = selectedFile.toURI().toURL().toString();
                Media media = new Media(filePath);
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                }
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
                mediaPlayer.play();
                isPlaying = true;
                updateTitleArtist(selectedFile.getName());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                System.out.println("Error loading file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

I have looked up the error but I haven't been able to find anyone else that has had this problem and the similar problems were all using Maven while I am using normal Java.

Do you declare the needed requires and exports in your module-info.java?

com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator (in unnamed module @0x4b92dfda) indicates that you are running some JavaFX components from the unnamed module (classpath) and not from a named module on the module path (which is the only supported configuration for JavaFX execution).  Info on defining dependencies (adjust for your build system) and Java modules that make use of JavaFX media.

Possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237287/module-error-when-running-javafx-media-application
